# I want to change the keyblind to accept the auto-completion from enter to tab for Tabnine in Atom

Tags: autocomplete, atom-editor

I want to when I press enter it will down the line not accept the auto-completion
Is there any way to change the accept key blind (enter) to another key blind (tab)?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

just change this option as you like.